# Action View Items Always fill the whole width of Action Bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

when I use action views, all action views are shown on the right side of action bar, I want them to fill the whole width of Action Bar, Is there a way to Specify weight for every item in the action bar?

Comment: Did you manage to do it ?

Comment: No, I used a View as Action Bar CustomView instead.

Comment: I see. This is also what I did. Was hoping for a more native way.